# Database returning false, cant figure out where i went wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am sorry to bother you with such a newbie question, and thank you for taking the time to go over it and answer it.

```
function dbaddusr($username, $email, $password){
        try{
            $conn = new PDO(CONNECTDATA);
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO 'users' ('username', 'email', 'password') VALUES (:username, :email, :password)");
            $pass = crypt($password);
            $result = $stmt->execute(array("username" => $username, "email" => $email, "password" => $pass));
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Problem is, $result is always false. (I discovered this by some simple var_dump statements inside the try block. 
I am very new to this and your help on fixing it is highly appreciated.

Comment: you're otputting the error message - what does it say? What do you output the error message for if you don't read it?

Comment: It doesnt trigger an error. The $result is false but there is no error message. THat is the confusing part.

Comment: Either you forgot to supply username and password or concatenated them into literal string with commas which would make no sense. Either way you will find the proper code from the link above

Comment: @aayushdagra: you're performing `echo`. Put `exit;` right after it and see

Comment: I var_dumped result and discovered that its false, and ofcourse the database never gets appended with the new data. Sadly i never actually caught the PDOException..

Comment: Also, You shouldn't connect every time you call a function. You'd kill your database server.

Comment: @zerk, i already tried that. I even put some code there and exit immediately afterwards, the exception was never even triggered.

Comment: @Common - I am very new and this is more of an experiment than anything else, if you know a better way then please tell me about it.

Comment: Duplicate of [PDO query fails but I can't see any errors. How to get an error message from PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15990858) (corrected link)

Comment: @YourCommonSense why are you not providing duplicates as closevotes? I've seen you do that several times now. You got the necessary reputation to do so, so please do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't quote the column names, if you want, use the backticks **`**

```
INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (:username, :email, :password)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `quotes` to `backticks` for table & column name in your query,

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `email`, `password`) VALUES      
        (:username, :email, :password)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing $pass in your array and your function accepts $password
Check your error messages to get specific details and you will find the problem.

Comment: He's generating $pass on this line `$pass = crypt($password);`

Comment: I think we've all done similar things; I know have, more than once.

Answer (score -1):

A non-bloated version with all useless and wrong code cleaned.

```
function dbaddusr($username, $email, $password){
    global $conn;
    $sql  = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $pass = crypt($password);
    $stmt->execute(array($username, $email, $pass));
}
```

You have to connect ONCE per application, and then use that single connection all the way.

Comment: Yeah, why "bloat" code with nasty stuff like exception handling and encapsulation.  Just make everything global and let the browser see your PHP errors...

Comment: The code I cleaned out was actually letting the browser to see your PHP errors.

Comment: While you have `global` in your answer, my down-vote will remain.  Your example perpetuates some of the worst habits among PHP developers.

Comment: @StevenMoseley - I would wrap the function call in a try catch, not have it within the method

Comment: @AlexP - You think a DAO should throw raw PDO exceptions?  I'm not saying it shouldn't throw an exception, but definitely not an unhandled one.